# adding a condition to a WHERE clause based on a passed variable value mysql

Tags: mysql

I am a relative novice and could use some help with this problem.

This will be used in a search filter situation.
Users need to search by a value and 1 or more other values passed by the search form.

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$sdate = $_POST['sdate'];
$startdate = $_POST['startdate'];
$enddate = $_POST['enddate'];
$vehicle = $_POST['vehicle'];
$triptype = $_POST['triptype'];
```

If any of these values are '' I do not want them in the query, If they contain a value I do want them in the query.

```
SELECT * FROM form_data WHERE `resp_person` = '$name', 
 IF $sdate != '' then `sdate` = '$sdate', 
 IF $startdate != '' then `sdate` = *all values between $startdate and $enddate*, 
 IF $triptype != '' then `triptype` = '$vehicle', 
 IF $vehicle != '' then `vehicle` = '$vehicle', `sdate`  
ORDER BY `sdate` DESC, `stime` DESC")
```

I know the code is wrong but it should give you a good idea of what I am trying to accomplish. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can test the variables *in PHP* whilst you build the SQL.

Comment: The variables are not the issue.  The solution I am looking for is how to code the IF statements ( or a suitable alternative) so they work within query.

Answer (score 1):

A better way is to not use string concatenation to build the entire query, but rather use an sql library that supports prepared statements, such as PDO.

```
$pdo = new PDO('... connection string ...', username, password);
$where = '';
$possible_values = array('name', 'sdate', 'startdate', 'enddate', 'vehicle', 'triptype' );
$params = array();
foreach($possible_values as $val)
{
    if(isset($_POST[$val]))
    {
        $params[] = $_POST[$val];
        if($where == '')
        {
            $where = "WHERE $val = ?";
        }
        else
        {
            $where .= " AND $val = ?";
        }
    }
}
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM form_data " . $where);
$stmt->execute($params);
```

Comment: pala_ ... Thank you for your suggestions.  I will try both and let you know how it worked.  Again, I am a relative novice but I think I understand this.

Comment: No problem. As a novice I really think it better for you if you focus on using prepared statements for your SQL - if you have time, look up SQL injection and why it's bad -- prepared statements are the best way to protect against these

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this, I prefer to build the query in pieces...

```
$wheres = array();   // Collect things to AND together
if ($searchterm != 'All')  $wheres[] = "subject LIKE '%searchterm'";
if (...)  $wheres[] = "...'";
...
if (count($wheres) > 0)
    $where_str = "WHERE " . implode(' AND ', $wheres);
else
    $where_str = '';

$order_str = (...) ? "ORDER BY ..." : '';

$limit_str = $limit ? "LIMIT $limit" : '';

$query = "SELECT ... FROM foo $where_str $order_str $limit_str";
```

Oh, and don't forget to use escape the strings on any data coming in from a form -- else a user can do nasty things to the SQL statement!

Comment: or better yet, convert the whole thing to pdo and use prepared statements

Comment: @pala_ Can PDO insert column names?

Comment: no - since the column names are well known ahead of time however, you can whitelist their allowance while building the prepared statement. there's no reason to encourage the use of string concatenation for the entire query

Comment: But you can't eliminate a clause with PDO.  That is, add `AND sdate = '...'` _only if_ the user filled in the "sdate" prompt in the <form>.

Comment: rubbish. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3ebcdb4639f313e3503d - pdo, optional (safe) columns, safe parameters, prepared statement goodness.

Comment: There are 2 things going on here:  (1) dynamically building the WHERE clause, (2) filling in the values.  #1 requires PHP code.

Comment: and the first thing does not preclude using a better method for the second thing

Comment: Rick... ... Thank you for your suggestions. I will try both and let you know how it worked. Again, I am a relative novice but I think I understand this.